# jqModal and ad-gallery

Tags: jquery, jqmodal

I found a great jquery gallery. (http://coffeescripter.com/2009/07/ad-gallery-a-jquery-gallery-plugin/) . I am trying to implement this in a jqmodal window but having some trouble.

To hide the jqmodal win, i have a file with:

```
<div id="jqmPix" class="jqmWindow" style="width:730px; display:none;">
```

on my main page:

```
  $('#jqmPix').jqm({modal:true});
  $('#clicky').click(function() {
   $('#jqmbPix').jqmShow();
```

});

The problem is when jqmShow() triggers, it messes up the ad-gallery's css. The main image disappears, and the thumbnails appear vertically instead of horizontally. IF i remove display:none from the jqmPix div, then it will work just fine. I tried $('#jqmPix').hide() as well. What can i do? thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure if this is the best answer but this is what I did:

I removed display:none, and put:

```
  $('#jqmPix').css('visibility','visible');
```

on the main page doc.ready. Then i have the following ajax call:

```
 showPix = function(bhiid,projNum) {

    $.ajax({
        type: "get",        
        url: "myURL",
        data: formData,        
        cache: false,       
        success: function(result) { 
                 $('#jqmPix').css('visibility','visible');
                                 $('#jqmbPix').jqmShow();

             .... }

    });
}
```

My next issue is the main div is not being moved to the right behind the ad-gallery.